# Can DocuSign Connect send JSON data

Tags: docusignapi

I am sending an envelope out for signature with eventNotifications turned on. I am wondering if the data DocuSign Connect sends back can be formatted in JSON or is XML the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Messages from DocuSign Connect will always be in XML format; receiving messages in JSON is not (currently) an option.

Comment: I posted a Docusign API question on Friday and haven't gotten any response, could you take a look please? (Q in my profile)